# Group search results by content type and limit count

Tags: search

I am trying to group search results by its content type. Also, I want to show not more than 4 results per content type.

For an assumption, it should look like this:
**Content type1-**
  Result1
  Result2
  Result3
  Result4
**Content type2-**
  Result5
  Result6
...

I am able to achieve this using TEMPLATE_preprocess_search_results().

```
function custom_preprocess_search_results(&$variables) {
  $variables['search_results'] = '';
  $resultTypes = array();

  // Divide results
  foreach ($variables['results'] as $result) {
    $resultTypes[$result['bundle']][] = $result;   
  }

  // Create fieldsets
  foreach ($resultTypes as $resultType => $resultTypeResults) {
    $value = '';
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($resultTypeResults as $result) {
      $value .= theme('search_result', array('result' => $result, 'module' => $variables['module']));
      $i++;
      if ($i == 4) {
        $value .= l(t('Show more'), current_path(), array('query' => array()));
        break;
      }
    }

  $variables['search_results'] .= theme('fieldset', array('element' => array('#title' => $resultType, '#children' => $value));
  }
}
```

But this is not an optimal method, since I trimmed down the results per content type (but actually they exist). Say if Content type1 has 10 actual results and Solr's maximum results per page is set to 10, then I will end up showing first 4 results of only Content type1.

Please suggest an ideal method to list 'n' matched results of every content type.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can increase the page limit by apache solr hook

```
function custom_apachesolr_query_alter($query) {
  if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/bundle/') == false)
    {
  $query->replaceParam('rows', '400'); // Note that high value increases response time
  }
}
```